# phase angle in fft fortran

Tags: fft, fortran90

hello this question may seem stupid but i'm new to any sort of programming. I just did the fourier transform (using a subroutine provided to me) of a data and got the values in complex format , which looks like this:

(-1.6391770E-08,-0.3750000)
(1.6391770E-08,0.3750000)
..............etc

i saved these format in a dat file. Now i need to calculate the phase angle of this data, i tried to use 'atan2(y,x)' intrinsic function but it needs real and imaginary data as x and y separately. I don't know how to extract these x and y from the complex format of above. I tried to use open and read function but it didn't work as there was bracket before and after the data in dat file. Am i missing something here? I need to find out the phase of the fft data. Thanks in advance for the help and sorry if my question is vague, if so i will try to make it clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your problem is, or perhaps you have several problems.  If you have a complex variable called, say, `z`, then you can pass its real and imaginary components to `atan2` with a call such as

```
atan2(aimag(z),real(z))
```

The functions `real` and `aimag` extract the components of a complex number.  If you are working with non-default kinds then these functions also understand kinds, so a call such as `real(z,real64)` will, if `real64` is a kind-type parameter, extract the real component of `z` with `real64` kind.

Note that these functions are both `elemental` which means that they can be applied to each element of an array and return an array of elements; so a call such as

```
real(z_array)
```

will return an array of reals with the same shape as `z_array`.

It looks to me as if you should be able to read the complex values directly from the file and then decompose them for your calls to `atan2`.

Comment: the first one solved my problem. Thank you.and it's been barely a month i've started programming so yeah i still have several problems and i'm working in it. thank you once again